# Spring step does not run properly when I "fib" the reader, must I use a tasklet?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-mybatis

I'm aware that all spring steps need to have a reader, a writer, and optionally a processor. So even though my step only needs a writer, I am also fibbing a reader that does nothing but make spring happy.

This is based on the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202241/how-to-write-a-spring-batch-step-without-an-itemwriter). Is it outdated, or am I missing something?

I have a spring batch job that has two chunked steps. My first step, `deleteCount`, is just deleting all rows from the table so that the second step has a clean slate. This means my first step doesn't need a reader, so I followed the above linked stackoverflow solution and created a `NoOpItemReader`, and added it to my `stepbuilder` object (code at the bottom).

My writer is mapped to a simple SQL statement that deletes all the rows from the table (code is at the bottom).

My table is not being cleared by the `deleteCounts` step. I suspect it's because I'm fibbing the reader.

I am expecting that `deleteCounts` will delete all rows from the table, yet it is not - and I suspect it's because of my "fibbed" reader but am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

My delete statement:

```
<delete id="delete">
    DELETE FROM ${schemaname}.DERP
</delete>
```

My deleteCounts Step:

```
@Bean
@JobScope
public Step deleteCounts() {
    StepBuilder sb = stepBuilderFactory.get("deleteCounts");
    SimpleStepBuilder<ProcessedCountData, ProcessedCountData> ssb = sb.<ProcessedCountData, ProcessedCountData>chunk(10);
    ssb.reader(noOpItemReader());
    ssb.writer(writerFactory.myBatisBatchWriter(COUNT_DATA_DELETE));
    ssb.startLimit(1);
    ssb.allowStartIfComplete(true);
    return ssb.build();
}
```

My NoOpItemReader, based on the previously linked solution on stackoverflow:

```
public NoOpItemReader<? extends ProcessedCountData> noOpItemReader() {
    return new NoOpItemReader<>();
}

// for steps that do not need to read anything
public class NoOpItemReader<T> implements ItemReader<T> {

    @Override
    public T read() throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I left out some mybatis plumbing, since I know that is working (step 2 is much more involved with the mybatis stuff, and step 2 is inserting rows just fine. deleting is so simple, it must be something with my step config...)

Comment: If you only need a writer, why are you not using a `Tasklet`?

Comment: @MichaelMinella I realized after writing this code that I could instead use a `Tasklet`. I am wondering, however, why this doesn't work to improve my understanding of spring batch. Based on previous stack overflow answers, I would think that using that `noopitemreader` would work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `NoOpItemReader` returns `null`.  An `ItemReader` returning `null` indicates that the input has been exhausted.  Since, in your case, that's all it returns, the framework assumes that there was no input in the first place.

Comment: I see. I incorrectly assumed that the stack overflow solution I linked in the question would extend to work for Readers as well as Writers. That is an incorrect assumption, yes?